# "Места не столь отдаленные"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло это выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дореволюционной России для ссылки заключенных существовало два места: "Места Сибири не столь отдаленные" и "Места Сибири отдаленные". Сейчас это выражение обозначает ссылку вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Про Сибирь = правильно.
[Места не столь отдаленные](http://www.rg.ru/2008/05/22/koroleva.html).

Правда, здесь уважаемая Марина Александровна слегка запуталась с географией. Западная Сибирь никак не дальше Восточной. Если, конечно, не с Сахалина ехать. 
Да и на "европейской территории России" Сибирей не бывает. Ни отдаленных, при приближенных.
Фактически Российская империя (за исключением Финляндии, Кавказа, Польши, Русской Америки и нескольких мелких территорий) делилась на три  большие зоны. Россия - в Европе, Сибирь - за Уралом и Туркестан - за Каспием.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, выражение перекликается с поговоркой "от тюрьмы да от сумы не зарекайся" и означает, что места эти могут нечаянно-негаданно оказаться совсем рядом (то есть говорящий допускает, что сам может там оказаться).